# Why is my C# method not called?

Tags: c#, .net

Why is my `X` method below not being called?!

```
static class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
       X((IEnumerable<int>)null);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> X<T>(IEnumerable<T> e)
    {
        if (e == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        yield break;
    }
}
```

I tried stepping into the debugger but it doesn't enter `X`! Is the `yield break` keyword causing some side effect I am not aware of?

If it's worth anything, I'm using Visual Studio 2008 Express with .NET 3.5 SP1.

Comment: I have minimized the example to contain only X, removing X2.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

X2 is an iterator and is delayed executed.  It won't be actually run until you attempt to get a value from the returned IEnumerable instance.  You can fix this to get the behavior you are actually wanting by breaking the function up into 2 parts.

```
   public static IEnumerable<T> X2<T>(IEnumerable<T> e)
   {
        if (e == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        return X2Helper(e);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<T> X2Helper<T>(IEnumerable<T> e)
    {
        yield break;
    }
```

Eric has a great blog post on this subject: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/08/high-maintenance.aspx

Comment: Oh, I forgot that part. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the method doesn't get called until the IEnumerable's GetEnumerator method is called.

Answer (score 0):

Your Main() method also needs to be public. Otherwise, other assemblies can't invoke your class's Main() method as the starting point of the application.

Comment: Why would other assemblies want to invoke my main method? I can't think of a reason for that.